# Not Able to understand the working of scanner object and its method ( nextInt, next, nextLine)

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, user-input

I have below lines of code. I am not able to understand, how input is being read line by line using `Scanner`:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HackerRank
{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("================================");
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
      String s1=sc.next();
      int s2 = sc.nextInt();
      sc.nextLine();
      System.out.printf("%-15s%03d%n", s1,s2);
    }
    System.out.println("================================");
  }
```

Standard Input:

```
Java 100
CPP 65
Python 125
```

Also, please let me know what change does it make if I am using `sc.nextLine();` after the `printf` statement.

Comment: Post code as text, NOT as screenshots. And what exactly do you not understand? Have you read the documentation? Have you debugged the program to see what each call returns?

Answer (score 2):

Let's take a look at this input (ignoring the for-loop):

```
Java 100
```

You have this 3 lines of code:

```java
String s1=sc.next();   //Line 1
int s2 = sc.nextInt(); //Line 2
sc.nextLine();         //Line 3
```

- Line 1 reads the 1st part of the input (Java)
- Line 2 reads the `int`-value, which is the second part of the input
- Line 3 reads the linebreak if you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> at the end of each line

Without the `sc.nextLine()`, other variations of the input would also produce the same output.

E.g the input in one line

```
Java 100 CPP 65 Python 125
```

would then also produce this output:

```
Java           100
CPP            065
Python         125
```

With the `sc.nextLine();` the rest of the line would be skipped if there is any following input in this line.

Then, the one-line input

```
Java 100 CPP 65
```

would only print the first two elements of the input:

```
Java           100
```

If you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> after each input, there is no difference in switching the `sc.nextLine()` and the `printf` lines in the code.

Answer (score 1):

The nextInt() method returns the next integer in the next line of the input. The next() method returns the next complete token from the scanner. The nextLine() method "advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped."

This [page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) will be helpful.

Comment: Hi Dharman/Spartan, 
I have gone through the your comments above and read the page mentioned too.
I helped me in clearing my doubts. Now I am good with Inputs which are given in Single line 
For eg. 
Java 100 CPP 65 etc.
But I am still not clearing about how input are read by scanner obj when they are given in multiple line 
Like 
Java 100
CPP 65 
Pyth 125

Comment: @csalmhof- Can you please help me with below queries:
I have below questions related to scanner obj:
 1. Is It correct Statement: - When Scanner Obj is called, User is giving the input in Single line 
           For Eg. Java 100 then Input will go like Java 100\n. i.e. \n get appended to input which tells system that user has given the input

Comment: 2.  2. If user is giving the input in multiline like:
 Java 100 - Line 1
 CPP 65 - Line 2
 Pyth 125 - Line 3
 How input will be converted :
 Option1: 
 Java 100 \n
 CPP 65 \n
 Pyth 125 \n
  or 
 Option 2:
 Java 100
 CPP 65
        Pyth 125 \n

Comment: 3. How tokens are created when user gives input in case of multiline
        4.     I am getting two different results when I am executing below two codes:
           Input ( at one go) :
           Java 100
           CPP 65 
           Pyth 125
          Code 1: